# System.IO.IOException when polling Siemens Logo device

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, modbus, windows-10-iot-core, siemens

I am new to Modbus and UWA and i was trying to make an application that read the status of input 1, output 1 and output 2 from my Siemens Logo device (6ED1052-1HB08-0BA0 LOGO! 24RCE). The Logo is running a simple test program. Here is the code i come up with so far.

```
(other packages)
using EasyModbus;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace AC_C_Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {       
        private ModbusClient modbusClient;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.0.3", 502); // Replace with your device's IP address and port
            ReadModbusData_Click();
        }
        private async void ReadModbusData_Click()
        {
                modbusClient.Connect();
                while (true)
                {
                    // Read input 1
                    bool i1Value = modbusClient.ReadDiscreteInputs(0, 1)[0];"I1"
                    // Read output 1
                    bool q1Value = modbusClient.ReadCoils(0, 1)[0];

                    // Read output 1
                    bool q2Value = modbusClient.ReadCoils(1, 1)[0];

                    // Display the values in TextBlocks
                    InputStatusTextBlock.Text = "I1: " + i1Value.ToString();
                    //   Q1ValueTextBlock.Text = "Q1: " + q1Value.ToString();
                    //   Q2ValueTextBlock.Text = "Q2: " + q2Value.ToString();
                }                        
        }
    }
}
```

however the line `bool i1Value = modbusClient.ReadDiscreteInputs(0, 1)[0];` is giving me the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I do not know what is causing it, I have the device connected by Ethernet and have already configured my connection to be in range, and I already tried turning off my firewall and nothing changed.

or is there a better way to do what am trying to achieve?

I tried different Modbus packages and ended with the same issue.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by verifying Modbus connectivity using a known good program (e.g. [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)/[Modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)). However, in this case, it appears that you are connecting but the connection is being dropped as soon as a request is received. Can you please provide additional details re the Logo (i.e. Model number) and the program running on it?

Comment: @Brits sorry for the late response here is the model number:
6ED1052-1HB08-0BA0
LOGO! 24RCE

as for the program running on it, it is a simple test program that if input i1 is on(true) output 1Q and Q2 will turn one Q1 will turn on after 1 sec and Q2 will turn on after 3 sec, same thin when input i1 is turned off, the point of my program is to detect the status changes in these three registers.

also, how can I know the actual address if the registers? because I was trying nmodbus package before the one am using right now and it would ask me the register address of the inputs and outputs

Comment: This is why I suggest using an off the shelf app to perform initial testing (otherwise its hard to know if the issue is with the PLC or your code). As your questions are specific to the logo you might have more luck in the [dedicated forumn](https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/us/en/threads/324) (I've not used this unit).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Siemense PLC ladder.
Can recommend to copy your Discrete Input value to Boolean tag. Give this tag an address and read all your data as coils
`bool q1Value = modbusClient.ReadCoils(0, 3)[3];`

[image]